# how to periodically dump a set of database tables to a local machine from a psql database in a single bash script run on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, select, psql

I tried this but it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLENAMES="user_stats"
ssh -t railsapps@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p xxx bash -c "'

for TABLENAME in $TABLENAMES
do
    psql -d mydb -P format=unaligned -P tuples_only -P fieldsep=\, -c "SELECT * FROM $TABLENAME" > /tmp/$TABLENAME  
done
'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Postgres [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command, and stuff them all in to a single sql file, that you then run with `psql`. Then you can take that script and either feed it to `cron` on Mac OS X, or `launchd` to run the script periodically.